# Configuration of GridSearchCV for AdaBoost and its base learner

Tags: python, gridsearchcv, adaboost

I'm running grid search on AdaBoost with DecisionTreeClassifier as its base learner to get the best parameters for AdaBoost and DecisionTree.

The search on a dataset `(130000, 22)` has been running for 18 hours so I'm wondering if it's just another typical day of waiting for training or maybe there might be an issue with the set up.

Is the base-learner, grid search, training and params set up correctly?

```
ada_params = {"base_estimator__criterion" : ["gini", "entropy"],
              "base_estimator__splitter" :   ["best", "random"],
              "base_estimator__min_samples_leaf": [*np.arange(100,1500,100)],
              "base_estimator__max_depth": [5,10,13,15],
              "base_estimator__max_features": [5,10,15],
              "n_estimators": [500, 700, 1000, 1500],
              "learning_rate": [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.3]
}

dt_base_learner = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state = 42, max_features="auto", class_weight = "balanced")
ada_clf = AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator = dt_base_learner)

ada_search = GridSearchCV(ada_clf, param_grid=ada_params, scoring = 'f1', cv=kf)
ada_search.fit(scaled_X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, your GridSearch tests `14 * 4 * 3 * 4 * 4 = 2,688` different model configuration, each for a crossvalidation of an unknown number of splits. You should definitely try to reduce the number of combinations in the `GridSearchCV` or go for `RandomizedSearchCV` or `BayesSearchCV` from `skopt`.

Comment: I'm using 5f split. As an example, what GS config would you use? Of your two alternatives, which would you use and why?

Comment: I would start with a less exhaustive GS to get a feeling for the useful range of my hyperparameters and then specify a GS based on the results I see in my first GS. Anyway, that approach somewhat resembles that of Bayes Search only that it is much less efficient. I would usually go with Bayes Search, however, that is quite the extensive topic to be explained here. You could google something to the effect of "bayes search vs grid search" if you are interested in the topic.

Comment: I am re-running it with sparse params. Is my base-learner, grid search and training set up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Gridsearch will not finish until all joins are done, check the RandomSearchcv documentation and increase the joins a few at a time (n_iter) and put "-1" in "n_jobs" to parallelize as much as possible

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html